# Turn off echoing in terminal - Golang

Tags: go, terminal, echo, system, ioctl

I'm trying to Turn off echoing in the terminal, in the Golang,

Code:

```
func main() {
    
    STDINFILE := os.Stdin
    STDINFILENO := 0

    raw, err := unix.IoctlGetTermios(STDINFILENO, unix.TCGETA)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    rawState := *raw

    rawState.Lflag &^= unix.ECHO

    err = unix.IoctlSetTermios(STDINFILENO, unix.TCSAFLUSH, &rawState)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var charValue byte
    reader := bufio.NewReader(STDINFILE)
    
    for {
        var err error
        // read one byte
        charValue, err = reader.ReadByte()
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                fmt.Println("END OF FILE")
            }
        }
        // press q to quit.
        if charValue == 'q' {
            os.Exit(0)
        }

    }
}
```

But it's not working as expected

I'm still able to see the echoed value,

[image]

What I'm doing wrong, Can someone please point out to me or guide me?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using [`terminal.ReadPassword`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal#ReadPassword)?

Comment: Yes, the reason is trying to learn the concept at more fundamental level.

Comment: You could always see the `terminal.ReadPassword` implementation [here](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/master/ssh/terminal/util.go#L97-L114). It's more or less the same as yours, but instead of using `unix.TCGETA` and `unix.TCSAFLUSH` it uses `unix.TCGETS` and `unix.TCSETS`...

Comment: Please don't include screen shots of text. It is far better to copy and paste the text directly into the question.

Comment: @people downvoting, It would be appreciated if you could provide the reason for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The issue was with the `tcsetattr - parameters`**
`err = unix.IoctlSetTermios(STDINFILENO, unix.TCSAFLUSH, &rawState)`

With action `TCSAFLUSH`,

[DOC](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Mode-Functions.html) SUGGEST:

`TCSADRAIN
Make the change after waiting until all queued output has been written. You should usually use this option when changing parameters that affect output.
TCSAFLUSH
This is like TCSADRAIN, but also discards any queued input.`

So the `termios` in above case was sending back the character out to the left (the “master” pty), as `ECHO` was not off in this case until the output was written to the `shell` (the “slave” pty ).

Changing the action to `TCSANOW - the change shall occur immediately`  turned the echo off immediately.